# WSE 2.0 with SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui, wse2.0

Does SOAPUI (http://www.soapui.org) support the WSE 2.0 standards?  If not, any other utility recommended for testing?

Better wording (10/27/2009): Does SOAPUI support WS-Security (passing user/pass with the WS-Security standard).  If so, where do I specify the user/password specific to WS-Security (as opposed to basic authentication).

Comment: you don't often hear "wse2" and "standards" in the same sentence

Comment: @skaffman agreed and I don't think that sending SOAP messages via TCP is a "standard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: 
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t71885.html
and this:
http://www.soapui.org/userguide/projects/wss.html

I'll confirm when I have done it.

Neal

Answer (score 1):

WSE 2.0 is Microsoft's way of implementing (at least a subset of) the WS-* Standards

I would have to assume that SoapUI has no issues testing against the WS Standards so you should be fine.

Comment: How and where do I specify the user/pass for WS-Security?

Comment: I see the "AUT" tab, but not sure if that is WS-Security related, or might be "basic authentication".   When I check the WSS-Outgoing options, looks like an empty drop-down box appears.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that soapUI includes support for sending SOAP messages via TCP so the answer actually depends on what you mean by WSE 2.0 standards. If you mean industry standard specifications like WS-Security, WS-Addressing, etc, the answer might be yes. If you include sending SOAP messages via TCP, I don't think so.

(EDIT: Actually, the OP wants to know if soapUI supports WS-Security and, if so, how to do it. I'm adding details below.)

The [WS-Security Configuration](http://www.soapui.org/userguide/projects/wss.html) section of soapUI's User Guide explains how to configure Web Services Security, WS-Security, related settings in soapUI.